# Does $\text{Tr}(A\rho A^\dagger \sigma)-\text{Tr}(A^\dagger A\rho\sigma) \geq 0$ hold if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are positive semidefinite and Hermitian?

Tags: matrices, trace

Given an arbitrary $N\times N$ matrix $A$ and positive semidefinite $N\times N$ Hermitian matrices $\rho$ and $\sigma$ (i.e. $\rho, \sigma\geq 0$ and $\rho=\rho^\dagger, \sigma=\sigma^\dagger$),
does $\text{Tr}(A\rho A^\dagger \sigma)-\text{Tr}(A^\dagger A\rho\sigma) \geq 0$ always hold?

Comment: Could you please provide some context on how this question arose? Could you please also share whatever progress you've made so far?

Comment: What about $A(x,y)=(y,x)$ and $\rho=\sigma$ with $\rho(x,y)=(x,0)$. We have $$A^\dagger A \rho\sigma=A^2\rho\sigma=\rho^2=\rho$$ and hence $$\text{Tr}(A^\dagger A\rho \sigma)=1.$$ On the other hand, we have $$\rho(x,y)=(x,0)$$ thus $$(A\rho)(x,y)=(0,x)$$ and hence $$\sigma A\rho=0.$$ Therefore, $$\text{Tr}(A\rho A^\dagger \sigma)-\text{Tr}(A^\dagger A \rho\sigma)=0-1=-1<0.$$

Comment: Maybe you can give us the specific case you are interested in. I guess there are some conditions that make this true.

Comment: Why the same notation for matrices and integers?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What do you mean?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven $N$ is an integer and $A$ is a matrix

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I see :) I would hardly ever use $A$ to denote an integer.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I meant that both are uppercase and no bold is used

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Then I hope you are not offended by my answer. I am not a huge fan of boldfaced letters for matrices.

Comment: The answer to your question is definitely “no”, as $\text{Tr}(A^\dagger A\rho\sigma)$, unlike $\text{Tr}(A\rho A^\dagger \sigma)$, is not always a real number.

Comment: @user1551 I do not understand why either of them should be a complex number. Could you elaborate? If we had $\rho=\sigma$, then I see that $\text{Tr}(A^\dagger A \rho^2)=\text{Tr}(\vert A \rho \vert^2)$ is real (right?), but if they do not coincide I don't see how we can say that anything (probably I am just too tired at this point).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven E.g. $\operatorname{tr}\left[\pmatrix{2&0\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{4&2i\\ -2i&1}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}\right]=9-2i$.

Comment: @user1551 I am stupid, I meant to write real, not complex. I have no troubles believing that these traces can be complex (they generically are). What confused me is the part where you said one of them is supposed to be real.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The trace of $A\rho A^\dagger \sigma$ is always nonnegative, as it is equal to the trace of the positive semidefinite matrix $\sqrt{\sigma}A\rho A^\dagger\sqrt{\sigma}$.

Comment: @user1551 Right, thanks! Actually, you should make this an answer. Way better than what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments I gave a counterexample to the OP's statement. In fact, there is a huge class of counterexamples. The Arraki-Lieb-Thirring inequality tells us that for $A,B \in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}$ with $A,B\geq 0$ and $r\in [0,1), q\in (0,\infty)$ we have

$$ \text{Tr}((B^r A^r B^r)^q) \leq \text{Tr}((BAB)^{rq}). $$

Now, for $A=A^\dagger, A\geq 0$ and $\rho=B=\sigma, B\geq 0$, $q=2, r=1/2$ Arraki-Lieb-Thirring gives us

$$\text{Tr}( \rho A \rho A)= \text{Tr}((\rho^{1/2} A \rho^{1/2})^2) = \text{Tr}((\rho^{1/2} (A^2)^{1/2} \rho^{1/2})^2)  \leq \text{Tr}(\rho A^2 \rho),  $$
which is the reverse inequality of the OP.